# Guacamole get the key of the share link connection

Tags: java, http, guacamole

I'm working with guacamole 0.9.14 , I want to get the share link of the connection.
 So I'm using `http.get` and `http.post` to get the key .

At first , I got the token from

```
dns/guacamole/api/tokens
```

After that , I got the id connection and uuid session from `dns/guacamole/api/session/data/mysql/activeConnections?token=????`

Now I want to get the key from :

```
dns/guacamole/api/session/tunnels/uuidconnection/activeConnection/sharingCredentials/idsession?token=???
```

But I have this result :

```
{
    "message": "No such tunnel.",
    "translatableMessage": {
        "key": "No such tunnel.",
        "variables": null
    },
    "statusCode": null,
    "expected": null,
    "type": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

It seems that the token has changed when I did the `http.get` to get the id session and uuid connection.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The sharingCredentals REST call requires sharing profile name, in your example above this is "idsession" - it doesn't look like profile name (although anything can be set as name).

You can get available sharing profiles by using

```
api/session/tunnels/uuidconnection/activeConnection/connection/sharingProfiles?token=???
```

And then you can use

```
api/session/tunnels/uuidconnection/activeConnection/sharingCredentials/<profile-name>?token=???
```

to get the sharing key.